# How to reference variables in ansible's copy module？

Tags: ansible

In a playbook with role, I want to write the following task concisely, the current writing method is wrong.
I don’t want to write three tasks repeatedly.

Task as follow:

```yaml
 - name: push user profile
   copy: src=conf/.bashrc dest={{ item }}/.bashrc owner={{ item }} group={{ item }}
   with_items:
     - "{{ userhomedir }}"
     - "{{ user }}"
     - "{{ user }}"
```

vars as follow:

```
user: ['root', 'admin', 'demo']
userhomedir: ['/root', '/home/admin', '/home/demo']
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your vars structure, and usual conventions, we can use the `basename` [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) on elements of `userhomedir` to get the username. For e.g.

```
{{ '/root' | basename }}
#=> 'root'
{{ '/home/demo' | basename }}
#=> 'demo'
```

Same way, we can copy the file to home directory with appropriate ownership:

```yaml
 - name: push user profile
   copy: 
     src: 'conf/.bashrc'
     dest: '{{ item }}/.bashrc'
     owner: '{{ item | basename }}'
     group: '{{ item | basename }}'
   with_items: "{{ userhomedir }}"
```